# Attribute href doesn't work in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I've this html code in my template:

```
<a  class="icon icon-home pull-right" href="index.html"></a>
```

If I click on it, nothing happens and no redirect to index.html is done. If I substitute `href` value with another (for example "`#/friend`") it is correctly written in the URL and caught by router. I don't understand the reason. The current URL I'm into when I try this is:

```
file:///C:/Users/Stefano/workspace/SocialGossip/assets/www/index.html#/back
```

Comment: This is probably what you want to do`<a  class="icon icon-home pull-right" href="/"></a>`

Comment: The problem is this:when click on icon the url doesn't change, but I can see url setted on its href value at the bottom of browser